# Store and retrieve password in database

Tags: zend-framework, encryption, passwords

I am developing an app which uses several API services, the API requires that I provide username and password for API transactions, unfortunately no API token :-( in-order to automate I need to store username passwords somewhere, preferably database, I cannot use hashing because I need to send the username/password to authenticate and process API request, hence I am wondering how to go about it.

If I use [Zend\Crypt](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.crypt.introduction.html) to encrypt and store the password in database and decrypt whenever required, would this be enough for security? is there something else I must consider?

Looking for pointers.

PS: I am using ZendFramework2 with Doctrine/MySQL for the app.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use a token mechanism (like OAuth). If that's not possible, one would use TLS/SSL client authentication.

However, if you rely on plain passwords (on the application-level, I still guess the username/password tupel is transmitted over a secure connection!) and you want to store them encrypted, you have to think of a meaningful mechanism to get an encryption key for your scenario. Just generating an encryption key and storing it on the same machine in plain does not provide more security.

Without more information on your scenario it is hard to make a suitable suggestion.